# iPod touch 4th Gen stopped working with iHome iP90

Tags: ipod-touch, accessories

I have an iPod touch 4th generation that I had been using with my iHome iP90 until today.  All of a sudden today I get a message saying that "This accessory is not supported"  Then when I remove my touch the sound no longer works.  When I reboot my sound returns.  Any ideas?  Really confused because all was fine until today.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade the firmware on your touch, say to 4.3?

Comment: I updated a few weeks ago but it was working fine after that

Comment: That's odd. Is the connector at the bottom bent? Does wiggling it while docked help?

Comment: I stuck it in another older IP90 and it worked fine.  So then I blew it and the IP90 out with compressed air and now it works.  I'm not convinced it was the air though, we will see if it returns.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stuck it in another older IP90 and it worked fine. So then I blew it and the IP90 out with compressed air and now it works. I'm not convinced it was the air though, we will see if it returns. Thanks.